# How to fetch data in proper format in ckeditor in angular?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am using [ckeditor4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4) [2.2.2] npm package in angular[v12].
I want to set this value in my ckeditor.

```
Hi Tata,\r\n\r\nGreetings from Flitpay.\r\n\r\nI am aman,
```

but i got data like this.
[image]

It ignores \r and \n.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

ckEditor takes html content as its data. Html does not recognize \n and \r.
Instead why don't you use some block HTML elements like

```
<p>Hi Tata,</p>Greetings from Flitpay.<p></p><p>I am Aman</p>
```